# Postfix sending email as root@localhost.foo.com

Tags: python, django, sentry

We deployed sentry on premise. We have no problems sending email through the applications. Sender shows "tail@foo.com" in the email.

However, there is celery worker that sends out emails, since the sender is "roo@localhost.foo.com" emails are bounced.

I have tried configuring `generic` and added hosname in main.cf. But didnt work.

My problem is postfix is sending emails as `root@localhost.foo.com` not as `tail@foo.com`.

What do I need to change or do to have the emails sent as `tail@foo.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`masquerade_domains` setting](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) as a workaround using this command:

```
$ postconf 'masquerade_domains = $mydomain'
```

> **masquerade_domains (default: empty)**
>
> Optional list of domains whose subdomain structure will be stripped off in email addresses.